# @BeforeMethod, is getting skipped and tests are failing

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I'm having the following problem, when i run my test suite on jenkins an some of my tests are getting skipped (about 45 tests out of 180). Here is my @beforeMethod

```
@Parameters({"subModel", "moduleName", "testName", "testLinkName"})
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeTest(String subModel, String moduleName, String testName, String testLinkName)
{
    this.subModel=subModel;
    this.moduleName = moduleName;
    this.testName = testName;
    this.testLinkName = testLinkName;
}


@BeforeMethod
public void handleTestMethodName(Method method) throws Exception
{
    this.testMethod = method.getName();
    this.testClass = method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
    initializeSelenium();
    String modulo = "";
    if(subModel.equalsIgnoreCase("ISSUER")){
        modulo = PropertiesManager.getInstance().getProperty(EPropertiesNames.MOD_ISSUER);
    }else{
        modulo = PropertiesManager.getInstance().getProperty(EPropertiesNames.MOD_ACQUIRER);
    }
    setCMSModulo(modulo);
    startAccess();
}
```

The method that is failing, is handleTestMethodName, and I have no idea what could be the issue. Im getting the following exception: "Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure."

I have the lasted chromedriver.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have two `@BeforeMethod`s here. Does your test runner support multiples?

Comment: I'm running the tests on testNG, and I haven't had any problems

Comment: Can you guarantee what order they will get run? If handleTestMethodName() is run before beforeTest(), that is going to be a problem?

Comment: Nope I can't guarantee that I'm assuming that they are being run in the order written.